# SQL trigger with IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables: `Table1` is all the companies, `Table2` is companies whose name start with A.

- Table1  `company (companyId int, companyName varchar(50), companySize int)`
- Table2  `companyStartWithA (companyId int, companyName varchar(50), companySize int)`

What I want to do is to create a trigger so that when I insert/update/delete something in `Table1`, it will automatically do the same in `Table2`

My code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER A_TRG_InsertSyncEmp 
ON company
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO companyStartWithA 
        SELECT *
        FROM INSERTED
        WHERE inserted.companyName LIKE 'A%'
END
```

And I get an error:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'companyStartWithA' can only be specified when a column list is used and `IDENTITY_INSERT` is `ON`.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Tag properly.  MySQL or SQL Server????  Can't be both.

Comment: What does this have to do with `ms-office`?

Comment: Remove the `Identity` on `Table2`.

Comment: it is microsft SQL server management studio

Comment: Why in the world do you want to create a copy of your data like this? This should be a view instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the fact that you're *not* explicitly specifying the column in the `INSERT` statement, and using a `SELECT *` to fill the data. Both are big no-no's - you should **always explicitly specify** the column that you want to insert into, and you should **always explicitly specify** the columns that you want to select. Doing so will fix this problem:

```
CREATE TRIGGER A_TRG_InsertSyncEmp 
ON company
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO companyStartWithA (companyName, companySize)
        SELECT companyName, companySize
        FROM INSERTED
        WHERE inserted.companyName LIKE 'A%'
END
```

But as Sean Lange absolutely correctly commented - this should **really** be just a **view** rather than a separate table.....

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CompanyStartsWithA
AS 
    SELECT companyId, companyName, companySize
    FROM dbo.Company
    WHERE Name LIKE 'A%'
```

and then you don't need any messy triggers or anything - just insert into `dbo.Company` and all companies with a name that starts with an `A` will be visible in this view....